# Why is the hashCode instance method not named as getHashCode in Java?

Tags: java

In order to obtain the hash code of an object in Java, we use the `hashCode()` method.

To access (private) fields in Java, by standard, we are expected to have separate method with `get` or `set` as prefixes based on the kind of operation the method is performing. So why is this different for the hashCode method?

Comment: The hashcode is not a value you set/get and saved in a private field. It's a calculated value.

Comment: With List you just call size and not getSize.

Comment: For fields, that may be the convention, but it's not the convention for "any method returning a value".

Comment: By the way: the `record` class also no longer uses `get...`.

Comment: @JoopEggen so records aren't JavaBeans...

Comment: @Kayaman right, and also Expression Language relies on `${foo}` becoming `getFoo()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `hashCode()` has been introduced with the first Java version, i.e. officially version 1.0.

The `getXXX()` and `setXXX()` paradigm was established later as part of the *JavaBeans* standard. JavaBeans defines a simple yet very useful component model by deriving properties from pairs of getters/setters. JavaBeans was introduced with JDK 1.1.

So `hashCode()` predates the getter/setter paradigm.

Comment: The convention of getter/setter methods was introduced in 1.1 but not follow for the `List` class that was introduced in 1.2. Is there any possibility that having `getXXX` or `setXXX` is purely for accessing private fields and not for values that are calculated (using private fields)?

Comment: The JavaBeans getter/setter convention is mandatory if something should appear as a property, e.g. in the JSP expression language. It doesn't matter whether it's private or public variable, or whether it's computed. The convention also serves a coding style guide. But it requires additional processes to ensure it's adhered to. At the time of JDK 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2, Java developed very quickly from nothing to a very popular language. There was no time and insufficient people to ensure all the conventions were adhered to.

Comment: Well, newer classes use indeed a pattern similar to `hashCode()` for immutable values, see `Runtime.version()`, `Console.charset()`, or `record`s in general. But I doubt that the developers have foreseen that they will turn to this pattern two decades later. Have a look at the “deprecated since 1.1” methods of [the AWT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html) to see how the Beans convention was established in 1.1. The Collection API is a different thing, as Collections are not Beans.

Answer (score 1):

In the end: conflicting paradigms.

Keep in mind that methods such as `hashCode()` are with java since day 0 more or less. And back then, there wasn't an established standard suggesting: use getters resp. an explicit "methods should be named `doWhatever()`".

And once released, renaming it to a more appropriate `computeHashcode()` or something alike would have broken all existing source code.

In other words: there is also a mindset of using very short method names, such as `size()` in the Collections interface.

Comment: Yes I guess this could be the main reason why it's still called as hashCode till date

Comment: The convention of getter/setter methods was introduced in 1.1 but not follow for the List class that was introduced in 1.2. Is there any possibility that having getXXX or setXXX is purely for accessing private fields and not for values that are calculated (using private fields)?

Comment: The getXXX / setXXX convention was established with JavaBeans. And there, it is definitely decoupled from private fields, but meant to address readable and changeable properties that are relevant to the outside world, regardless how they are implemented. That good intent quickly degraded into the bad habit to have every field exposed with a boilerplate getter and setter, thus breaking any desired encapsulation.